# Flexbox columns not keeping equal width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to position 5 blocks in the following way: I want to set 2 blocks horizontally, 1 block on bottom, and 2 blocks near the 3rd block vertically.

The problem is the width of the 1st cell is not equal to the width of the 3rd cell. How can I fix it?

See the code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kf1q4gq5/1/).

```css
.Group1,
.Group2 {
  display: flex;
}

.miniGroup {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.div1,
.div2,
.div3 {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.div1 {
  background: #ABC;
  display: flex;
}

.div2 {
  background: #DEF;
}

.div3 {
  background: #CAD;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="BiggestContainer">
    <div class="Group1">
      <div class="div1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.</div>


      <div class="div2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. </div>


    </div>
    <div class="Group2">
      <div class="div1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. </div>

      <div class="miniGroup">
        <div class="div2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
          consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
          elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. </div>
        <div class="div3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
          consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
          elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.Group1,
.Group2 {
  display: flex;
}

.miniGroup {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.div1,
.div2,
.div3 {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: calc(50vw - 80px);
}

.div1 {
  background: #ABC;
  display: flex;
}

.div2 {
  background: #DEF;
}

.div3 {
  background: #CAD;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="BiggestContainer">
    <div class="Group1">
      <div class="div1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.</div>


      <div class="div2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. </div>


    </div>
    <div class="Group2">
      <div class="div1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. </div>

      <div class="miniGroup">
        <div class="div2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
          consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
          elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. </div>
        <div class="div3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
          consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
          elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Can  I ask you why did you add this : "max-width: calc(50vw - 80px);" ?

Comment: @MikhailNono you have the original case flex different calculates the width of columns in groups. he needs help

Comment: Hm.. When the size of screen is not big everyting is fine, but when the size of screen is too big the code does not fix the problem.

Comment: @MikhailNono the size of screen is too big... how big? just tested the 1920x1200 is no problem. Used ctrl + wheel - no problem.

Comment: @MikhailNono I guess that in a real project, you still have the paddings or margins. the calculation of this - half of the difference viewport minus all the padding and margins.

Answer (score 1):

Here a some ideas:

- Use `box-sizing: border-box`, so all padding is included in the width calculations.
- Treat the `miniGroup` like its sibling flex items. In other words, give it similar margin and padding to `div1` and `div2`. Then adjust the padding/margin of its children.
- Remind the `miniGroup` that it needs to be 50% width.

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kf1q4gq5/3/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.Group1, .Group2 {
  display: flex;
}
.miniGroup {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 10px;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
.miniGroup > .div2, .div3 {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
.div1, .div2 {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.div1 { background: #ABC; }
.div2 { background: #DEF; }
.div3 { background: #CAD; }
```

```html
<div class="BiggestContainer">
  <div class="Group1">
    <div class="div1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
      consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
      Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.</div>
    <div class="div2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
      consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
      Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Group2">
    <div class="div1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
      consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
      Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. </div>
    <div class="miniGroup">
      <div class="div2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. </div>
      <div class="div3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
.Group1, .Group2 {
    display: flex;
}
.miniGroup {
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.div1, .div2, .div3{
  border-style: solid;
}
.div1 {
  background: #ABC;
  display: flex;

}
.div2 {
  background: #DEF;
}
.div3 {
  background: #CAD;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div class="BiggestContainer">
    <div class="Group1">
        <div class="div1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.</div>


            <div class="div2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. </div>        


  </div>
  <div class="Group2">
        <div class="div1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. </div>

        <div class="miniGroup">
            <div class="div2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. </div>
            <div class="div3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam magnam provident deserunt, deleniti neque vitae soluta id eveniet inventore animi laudantium iste vero, cupiditate doloremque et sint, dolor unde ab. </div>
        </div>

  </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

[JSFliddle Result](https://jsfiddle.net/ga04cn16/)